# Performance of vectorization in Julia

Tags: julia

I can replicate the code from `In [1]:` to `In [6]:` of [this page](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julialang.github.com/blob/master/blog/_posts/moredots/More-Dots.ipynb)

The benchmark test shows `newvec!` runs faster than `vec!`

However, running

```
@time vec!(X);
@time devec!(X);
@time newvec!(X);
```

gives

```
0.056178 seconds (29 allocations: 91.554 MB, 20.38% gc time)
0.006899 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
0.124931 seconds (22 allocations: 53.407 MB, 79.26% gc time)
```

Why does `vec!` run faster than `newvec!` in this case?

What is the difference?

(I tried the same code several times but the result is same)

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: The benchmarks you link to are for v0.6, showing off new functionality that didn't exist in v0.5.

Comment: I am using 0.5.1

Does it mean the benchmark test reports something wrong?

Comment: No, it just means that you're using the wrong version of Julia to reproduce those benchmarks.  This fast fused vectorization is a new feature in 0.6.  You can either wait for the release or try the alpha.